# Webworker is not running

Tags: html, web-worker

I have the following code:

```
var stressWorker = new Worker("./test/webworkers/worker.js");
stressWorker.onmessage = function(event){
    alert(event.data);
};
stressWorker.onerror = function(event){
    throw new Error(event.message + " (" + event.filename + ":" + event.lineno + ")");
};
```

worker.js:

```
onmessage = function(e){
   postMessage("test");
}
```

The script finds the 'worker.js' file but it doesn't actually run it. What am I doing wrong?

PS. I'm hosting both scripts using wamp and I'm using chrome

Answer (score 1):

worker.js won't do anything until it receives a message. I can't see where you are sending it a message. You need something like `stressWorker.postMessage(...)` somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your **browser supports** this particular HTML5 feature?

[This article](http://diveintohtml5.info/everything.html) has many ways to test for support of each feature. The test for Worker is

```
return !!window.Worker;
```

**Edit**: As I see it, there's either a problem with your code or it can't find the file. Your code looks a lot like [this example](http://blogs.sitepoint.com/javascript-threading-html5-web-workers/) except there the .js file code is like this, with the `self`:

```
self.onmessage = function(e) {  
    self.postMessage("Hello " + e.data);  
};
```

It should be easy enough for you to try that and see if it's the missing piece here.

Comment: yes, I'm using chrome and that snippet of code returned true.

Answer (score 0):

One main thing You should remember If you are running scripts on same origin and using chrome, you should start the chrome with the flag **--allow-file-access-from-files** or You should run app on **local server**.

See the code

```
 var stressWorker = new Worker("../test/webworkers/worker.js");
    stressWorker.onmessage = function(event){
        alert(event.data);
    };
    stressWorker.postMessage("Hello there");
    stressWorker.onerror = function(event){
        throw new Error(event.message + " (" + event.filename + ":" + event.lineno + ")");
    };
```

Now you will get The response from the worker. ".."  I suspect path is wrong.